# Unable to use query parameters

Tags: json, firebase

I am trying to use the new query parameters to do searches for elements based off child values. Ideally, I want to be able to do something like

`https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/.json?orderBy="hash"&startAt=123&endAt=123`

to get a specific element as long as I have given it a unique hash value. In my course to do this, i realized I couldn't do any sorting except for using orderBy="$key". I even went so far as to make a clone of the demo dinosaur-facts data set. I exported the data using the 'export json' button, then imported it into my data set using the 'import json' button, and verified that all the data is the same. I then tried to do the demo queries outlined [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries), replacing the "dinosaur-facts" with my own domain, and it STILL doesn't work.

When I try

```
curl https://myapp.firebaseio.com/.json?orderBy="height"
```

The error I get is:

```
{"error" : "Index not defined"}
```

However, if you try

```
curl https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/.json?orderBy="height"
```

You get exactly what you would expect, all the dinosaurs sorted by their height. Is this an issue with my rules? Why can't I do this functionality that is being claimed? Has it not been rolled out to everyone? Do I need to pass my secret token for every one of these? Because when I do that, I get an error saying my auth token could not be parsed. I really have no idea what is happening, I just want to be able to do queries...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to sort on a specific child, there must be an index on that child node. You can add such an index by adding an `.indexOn` rule to the security/rules in your dashboard, e.g.

```
       ".indexOn": ["hash"]
```

Most client-side APIs that Firebase provides have an implementation that of the ordering/filtering, which allows them to order/filter data even when no index is present. This is handy for development purposes.

But the REST API doesn't have a client-side, so ordering/filtering is only possible after you define the proper index.

See: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html:

> Indexes are not required for development **unless you are using the REST API**. The realtime client libraries can execute ad-hoc queries without specifying indexes. Performance will degrade as the data you query grows, so it is important to add indexes before you launch your app if you anticipate querying a large set of data.